# Code encryption using letter scores

Tags: java, encryption

I have a logical question.  What is the easiest way to turn a string into its "score" in java, for use of encryption and decryption.  Here is what I mean by score.

```
A = 1;
B = 2;
C = 3;
```

Ect.

I want to sort an entire string into one score, so "AABC" would = 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 7

I realize I can just set A to 1 and Z to 26, but this would be tedious and a waste of code.

Comment: Have a look at this link, it shows example for basic symmetric encryption http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/Basicsymmetricencryptionexample.htm

Comment: You could use the character ordinal value minus its offset. If we're talking of just the English letters is even simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        String s = "AABC";
        long score = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
        {
            score += s.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1;
            //Basically, you check every index of the string and convert
            //each character into its score and add them.
        }
        System.out.println(score);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
    char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();

    int total = 0;
    for(char c : charArray)
    {
        total = total + ((int)c) - 64;
    }

    System.out.println("Total : "+total);
```